# How to query a table based on up to 17 different variables?

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic

I have a MySQL table which I wish to search via a POSTed form. The trouble is there are some 17 variables that an end user may wish to query, either singly or in combination. This results in too many possibilities for else-if statements. After asking here, I've constructed the following query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM profiles"; 

$postParameters = array("name","height","gender","class","death","appro","born","tobiano","modifier","adult","birth","sire","dam","breeder","owner","breed","location");
$whereClause = " WHERE 1 = 1";
foreach ($postParameters as $param) {
    if (isset($_POST[$param]) && !empty($_POST[$param])) {
        switch ($param) {
            case "name":
                $whereClause .= " AND ProfileName='".$_POST[$param]."' ";
                break;
            case "height":
                $whereClause .= " AND ProfileHeight='".$_POST[$param]."' ";
                break;
            case "gender":
                $whereClause .= " AND ProfileGenderID='".$_POST[$param]."' ";
                break;
            case "class":
                $whereClause .= " AND ProfileBreedClassID='".$_POST[$param]."' ";
                break;
            case "death":
                $whereClause .= " AND ProfileYearOfDeath='".$_POST[$param]."' ";
                break;
            case "appro":
                $whereClause .= " AND ProfileYearApproved='".$_POST[$param]."' ";
                break;
            case "born":
                $whereClause .= " AND ProfileYearOfBirth='".$_POST[$param]."' ";
                break;
            case "tobiano":
                $whereClause .= " AND ProfileTobianoTest='".$_POST[$param]."' ";
                break;
            case "modifier":
                $whereClause .= " AND ProfileColourModifier='".$_POST[$param]."' ";
                break;
            case "adult":
                $whereClause .= " AND ProfileAdultColourID='".$_POST[$param]."' ";
                break;
            case "birth":
                $whereClause .= " AND ProfileBirthColourID='".$_POST[$param]."' ";
                break;
            case "sire":
                $whereClause .= " AND ProfileSireReg='".$_POST[$param]."' ";
                break;
            case "dam":
                $whereClause .= " AND ProfileDamReg='".$_POST[$param]."' ";
                break;
            case "breeder":
                $whereClause .= " AND ProfileBreederID='".$_POST[$param]."' ";
                break;
            case "owner":
                $whereClause .= " AND ProfileOwnerID='".$_POST[$param]."' ";
                break;
            case "breed":
                $whereClause .= " AND ProfileBreedID='".$_POST[$param]."' ";
                break;
            case "location":
                $whereClause .= " AND ProfileLocationCountryID='".$_POST[$param]."' ";
                break;
        }
    }
}
$query .= $whereClause;

$result = mysql_query("$query");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $row['ProfileName'] . '<br/>';
    }
```

Thanks to Saggi Malachi for this method!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach would be defining an array with all possible POST parameters and then running over them while you build your WHERE clause using a PHP switch statement.

```
<?php
$postParameters = array("name","height","gender");
$whereClause = " WHERE 1 = 1";
foreach ($postParameters as $param) {
    if (isset($_POST[$param]) && !empty($_POST[$param])) {
        switch ($param) {
            case "name":
                $whereClause .= " AND ProfileName='".$_POST[$param]."' ";
                break;
            case "height":
                $whereClause .= " AND ProfileHeight='".$_POST[$param]."' ";
                break;
            // more cases....  
        }
    }
}
$query .= $whereClause;
```

Comment: And how do I formulate that final query? $result = mysql_query($query);?

Comment: @Eamonn Yes, your changes in the isset line are correct. fixed my answer.

Comment: @Eamonn yes, use mysql_query. see http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php for examples.

Comment: @Saggi Malachi - Thanks Saggi! Should the version of your script that I posted in my question not now work? I'm getting a 'not a valid argument...' error (specifically on the 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
line)

Comment: Replace mysql_query('$query'); with mysql_query("$query");
(You must use double quotes for PHP to parse variables contained in your strings)

Answer (score 1):

Another way, a bit more flexible.

```
<?php

// Use $ to indicate variable name, $ will be stripped when getting data from $_POST.
// The $variable will then be replaced with the data from the form.
// This way you setup the entire condition in the array, more flexible.
$set_data = array(
    'ProfileHeight >= $height',
    'ProfileGenderID = $gender',
    'ProfileTobianoTest LIKE %$tobiano%',
    'ProfileOwnerID = $owner',
);

$where = '';
foreach ($set_data as $str) {
    // Get variable name from str.
    if (!preg_match('/\$([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/', $str, $matches))
        die('Invalid settings.');

    $name = $matches[1];

    if (!isset($_POST[$name]))
        continue;

    $data = trim($_POST[$name]);

    if ($where != '')
        $where .= ' AND ';
    $where .= str_replace('$' . $name, mysql_real_escape_string($data), $str);
}

if ($where != '') {
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE ' . $where;
    print "$query\n";
}
```

Comment: O wow, that looks efficient - I'm going to give that a go... Thanks Johan!

Answer (score 0):

The top one looks like it would work properly.

Have you tested them?

There was a typo in the first though:
'ProdileHeight' should be 'ProfileHeight' I assume

Comment: And you might want to add a space after the quotes: `" AND ProfileHeight LIKE..."`

Comment: When using the former method, do i need to POST the values of the form first? I'm used to having a list: $name = $_POST['name'], $height = $_POST['height'], etc... Is it ok to just have the 'raw' names in the query: WHERE ProfileGenderID = 'gender'?

Comment: Also, how to pass this in a query? 
$result = mysql_query(string query); ?

Comment: I would use a list too, that way you only reference the form data once. Try that query, otherwise try $query instead of string query.
php print the query to check to make sure that is has compiled properly first.
So try print string query; and print $query; and see which one prints the SQL (so do one at a time)
Then use that one in $result

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to make a few modifs:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM profiles"; 
$parameters = "";

foreach ($params as $param => $value)
{
    // Important! validate the content of $value to avoid SQL injections

    if (!empty(param))
    {
         $parameters .= "AND $param LIKE '%" . $value . "%' ";
    }
}
if (!empty($parameters))
{
    $parameters = preg_replace("/^AND/", "WHERE", $parameters, 1); 
}
```

This requires you to:

1. Rename your parameters to the exact names of the columns
2. Gather all the data in an array instead of separate variables
   By the way, it looks like you are not checking the parameter variables for SQL injection. If these are user submitted, you should.
3. Do all your comparisons using "LIKE". If this is a problem, you can make a couple special cases to take care of the "LIKE" parameters.

Assuming you are willing to do these changes, it's a lot cleaner.

BTW, you ask about PHP, but your code looks like C#. What gives?

Comment: None of the inputs are sanitized yet, but they will be, thanks :)  As regards the first snippet - it was based on a piece I found here, but I didn't recognise as PHP. Before I edited the question, I did ask whether it was, in fact PHP at all. Nobody came back on it, so I developed it as if it was. I still don't actually know if it is or not. Googling returns C# answers...

Comment: I can follow the syntax of Saggi's query, but am a bit confused by yours (my fault, not yours!). It's advanced stuff for me! Am I not listing parameters any more?

Comment: @Eamonn: It is not PHP, that much is for sure. In PHP variables start with "$". Anyway, to use my suggestion, you must gather the data in an array like this: $params["ProfileName"]="John"; As you can see the key of the array is the same as the column name. That way, instead of listing all the columns, you can just loop through the  array and get both the value and the column name. That said, if you find the other answer easier to understand, that's what you should use. Otherwise, you will have problems later maintaining your code.

Comment: Alrighty - thx tho - I'll reference this again when I know more :)